# Desktop interface in linux AMI in AWS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I've been fiddling around with AWS for the past two days, to see what I can do with it and how it would fit my needs. I've already installed LAMP (I installed WAMP on my own computer a long time ago) and R, Rserver & Shiny server.

The instance I ran is `Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03.2 (HVM), SSD Volume Type`, `t2.micro`.

I was wondering : is there a way to have some kind of desktop interface to navigate around ? Kind of like in Ubuntu - if I'm not wrong about what Ubuntu is (I'm brand new to Linux and really just trying stuff while I can break them).

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a [VNC server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) perhaps by following [these instructions](http://devopscube.com/setup-gui-for-amazon-ec2-linux/).